# Google chrome cannot work properly in windows remote desktop?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I want to run **only** google chrome program in remote desktop, so I set the program path and filename to chrome.exe as follows:

Program Path And FileName:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Start Path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\

please refer to the following picture for more details:

[program settings of Remote Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8aJt.jpg)

After connnecting successfully to remote windows server, chrome started, but it cannot work, no matter what website I type, there is no response.

[chrome does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Tcp.jpg)

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note:

1. If I use Internet Explorer instead of chrome in the same way, everytings is ok.
2. If I unset the program settins in remote desktop above, connect to remote server and then run chrome, it works.

Answer (score 1):

"%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-no-sandbox-job